# Implement custom func with completion handler

Tags: swift

I have just created a custom class for my purpose (export something to destination).

My extend class as below

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PBExtensionExport: NSObject {
    static let instance = PBExtensionExport()

    fileprivate var progress: Int = 0

    func exportPhotos(images: [UIImage], completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
        for image in images {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(updateStatus), nil)
            // Progress monitoring
            completion(images.count == progress)
        }
    }

    @objc private func updateStatus() {
        // Updating progress status
        progress += 1
    }
}
```

And this is how I called it in main proc:

```
PBExtensionExport.instance.exportPhotos(images: selectedImages, completion: { (success) -> Void in
        if success {
            // Do something
        } else {

        }
    })
```

The problem is no compile error. But when I run my code, the command display runtime exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
>   reason: '-[NSInvocation setArgument:atIndex:]: index (2) out of bounds [-1, 1]'

Can anyone explain this problem for me please?

Comment: BTW you can just put `completion(images.count == progress)`

Comment: On what line does it crash?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth thanks you, I updated my code, but can you explain main problem for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `updateStatus` takes no arguments while `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`'s `completionSelector` parameter expects this method signature, according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum).

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image
    didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
                 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
```

In Swift, this would be something like

```
func updateStatus(image: UIImage, error: Error?, context: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: @DávidPásztor You seem to be misunderstanding the question. The Swift code in the docs you are referring to is the signature of the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` call itself, while I'm talking about the type of the function argument `completionSelector`. I included the steps to find my answer as OP seems inexperienced and I thought that it would help him understand it.

Comment: thanks you both. I'm researching. nice suggestion :)

Comment: @VicTran Great! If my answer resolved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark button thingy to the left of my answer

Answer (score -1):

You should go with Photos framework to save images. See below code with proper use of completion handler.

```
fileprivate var currentImageIndex = 0
typealias imagecompletionBlock = (_ isSuccess: Bool) -> Void
var arrImages:[UIImage]?

var imageSuccessBlock : imagecompletionBlock?

func saveImageToLibrary(images:[UIImage],completion:@escaping ((Bool) -> Void))
{

    self.imageSuccessBlock = completion
    self.currentImageIndex = 0

}

func saveImage()
{
    if self.currentImageIndex == self.arrImages?.count
    {
        self.imageSuccessBlock!(true)
    }else{
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: self.arrImages![self.currentImageIndex])
        }, completionHandler: { success, error in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if success {
                    // Saved successfully!
                    self.saveImage()
                }
                else if let error = error {
                    // Save photo failed with error
                }
                else {
                    // Save photo failed with no error
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but I don't want to use framework, I wanna do it by myself. I will refer this. :D

Comment: yes it's upto you but you can replicate same behaviour for completion handler using writeToAlbum method.

Comment: it's DONE, guy. thanks you so much, it worked correctly! :D